# Default Controller in created new project in ASP.NET MVC. How to remove safely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUu4F.png)

I want to remove these Controllers and Views safely. But I get error also in Startup.cs

Comment: "I get error" isn't helpful information. **What** does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your routes :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=NewDefaultControllerName}/{action=NewDefaultMethod}/{id?}");
            });
```